# Using gcc instead of clang in ghci or ghc

Tags: macos, haskell, gcc, ghc, ghci

On Mac OSX 10.9, the default c compiler bundled with `Xcode` is `clang`. I installed `gcc-4.9` with `homebrew`. Now I have two different `gcc`s, one is `clang`, the other is `gcc`. The default is `clang`.

I want to use `gcc` when compiling Haskell files with `ghc`, and I want also `gcc` when I launch `ghci`. How to do this change?

Comment: As far as I understood, the default ghc compiler now goes directly to LLVM bytecode, rather than through intermediate C.

Comment: @Impredicative While code generation is either native or via LLVM now, the C compiler is still called for other tasks such as linking.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Reproducing my directions I've been sharing with haskellers for the past few months via https://gist.github.com/cartazio/7131371

1. Type `ghc --print-libdir`

   The output will be a path like `/Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/7.6.3-x86_64/usr/lib/ghc-7.6.3`
2. Go to that directory and edit the `settings` file.
3. There'll be a line indicating the path to the C compiler. It'll probably say `/bin/gcc`
4. Change that line to `/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.8` (or whichever `gcc` version you brew installed, such as `/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2`)

Comment: Shall I only change `C compiler command` opition? What about other options? https://gist.github.com/eccstartup/7781154

Comment: Just what I say. Nothing else.

Comment: You may want to also make sure that the GCC in your path points to your GCC. And not the apple clang one.  Check by typing "gcc --version" from shell

Comment: important note: these directions are absolutely not needed / shouldn't be used with ghc 7.8 and 7.10. 1) they will configure fine as is 2) for those folks who move to OS X 10.10, only ghc 7.10 and newer will work, sorry :)

Comment: I simplified the steps for finding the settings file.

Comment: thanks reid! Hopefully everyones upgraded to ghc 7.10.2 by now so that these issues dont matter any more :)

Comment: This is very useful tip to customize ghc backend

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE: when compiling libraries that use OSX specific headers or such, you MAY have to use apple clang to get things to link correclty

Comment: This hack is useful to install ghc on gentoo i486, as the compiler configuration defaults to i686 instead.