# Change C compiler command in ghc on Linux

Tags: haskell, gcc, clang, ghc

How to switch compiler on linux in ghc from gcc to clang? `ghc --info` gives me

```
ghc --info
[("Project name","The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System")
,("GCC extra via C opts"," -fwrapv")
,("C compiler command","/usr/bin/gcc")
...
]
```

and I couldn't find a way to change path to compiler.
This question has been marked as duplicated, however [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349104/using-gcc-instead-of-clang-in-ghci-or-ghc) doesn't provide any solution as creating ~/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.6.3/settings with desired entries changes nothing on linux mint 17 or ubuntu 14.04 - that answer probably solves problem only on Mac OS X.

Comment: I think ghc is too tied to gcc. Why not use LLVM backend?

Comment: You can try -pgmc and friends, see https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.1/docs/html/users_guide/options-phases.html#replacing-phases No guarantee that it will work though.

Comment: You can certainly edit the `settings` file as described in that other answer. Another way to find it is `cat $(which ghc)` and look in the directory specified with the `-B` option.

Comment: To be precise: creating  ~/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.6.3/settings with desired entries changes nothing on linux mint 17 or ubuntu 14.04, so I don't duplicate question. @ReidBarton could you clarify what you mean by   -B option, please?

Comment: Have you read the output of `cat $(which ghc)`?

Comment: I'm trying to use `shake` build system to compile code which is linked with other libraries cross compiled with clang on mac os. That's why I'm trying to use clang on my machine.

Comment: Actually you can ask ghc for the location directly: `ghc --print-libdir` (it is also in the `ghc --info` output).

Comment: @ReidBarton yes, changing entry in `/usr/lib/ghc/settings` works. Thanks!

Comment: @ReidBarton if you change your comment to an answer, I could mark it  as answered.